# MS Access Listbox - After adding item from fields, all calculated fields go to "#Error" and "#Type!"

Tags: vba, ms-access, listbox

This is a strange error which I only seem to get occasionally. When I do fix this issue, it happens randomly and I can never reproduce the problem/solution.

The situation is this. I have a form that has several fields, and when filled out and the user clicks the `Add` button, it will add the fields to the listbox called `Processing_Lb_R`. (See image below for how the form looks). The `Remnant Code`, `Weight`, and `New Cost` fields are calculated fields.

As you can see, these calculated fields are being calculated properly. When I click add, it gathers all of the necessary fields and attempts to insert them into the listbox at the top of the image (ignore the listbox below as it's irrelevant to this question).

Here is the add button `Click` event:

```vb
Private Sub Add_Button_R_Click()

    ' Validation happens here
    ' ...

    Dim jobNum As String
    jobNum = Job_Number_R.value

    remnantDict.Add Item_Type_R.value & "-" & Item_Code_R.value & "-" & jobNum, 1
    
    ' This code runs fine. The item is added to the listbox.
    ' Immediately after though, the value of the Remnant_Code goes to #Error, the value of Weight goes to #Type!, and the value of New_Cost goes to #Type!.
    Processing_Lb_R.AddItem (Item_Type_R.value & ";" & Item_Code_R.value & ";" & Job_Number_R.value & ";" & STD_Weight_Per_Ft_R.value & ";" & Category_R.value & ";" & Grade_R.value & ";" & Gauge_R.value & ";" & Width_R.value & ";" & Length_R.value & ";" & Remnant_Code_R.value & ";" & Quantity_R.value & ";" & Weight_R.value & ";" & New_CWT_R.value & ";" & New_Cost_R.value)
    
    ' This method depends on the calculated fields values. So it errors out since the values are invalid.
    addLocationValuesToLb
       
End Sub
```

At first, I thought it was because invalid characters were being added to the listbox which made it function weirdly (commas, semicolons, or even apostrophes) but that's not the case as you can see in my code and image of the field data below.

Then I thought that maybe there's an issue with Access where if the number of columns in the listbox don't match up with the number of items added, it will cause issues. That's also not the case as the listbox has 14 columns. Here is the format for the `Column Widths` property:

```
2.501cm;5cm;2cm;0cm;0cm;0cm;0cm;0cm;0cm;5cm;1.524cm;2cm;2cm;2cm
```

and if you look at the statement where I add an item to the listbox, there are 14 items.

Why is this error happening? Why are all the calculated fields recalculating and resulting in invalid values right after I add to a listbox which has nothing to do with the values of the fields changing? Is there an event that is firing when I add to a listbox causing these changes?

Thanks

[image]

**EDIT:**

I add these values to the listbox because after I click add and they get inserted to the listbox, the user can fill out the fields again and add more data. The idea is that nothing gets inserted to the table until the moment they click the `Submit` button. So they can add/remove data from the listbox without touching any of the tables.

Here are the functions for the calculated fields. I don't believe the contents of these functions are important for this issue, since like I said the error with the calculation only comes up once I add an item to the listbox. I do not tough any of the form fields that the calculation relies on.

Here is the code for the weight calculation:

```vb
Public Function calculateWeight(itemCode As String, quantityVal As Variant, Optional itemType As String) As Long

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    ' If any of the fields are empty, set weight to 0
    If Trim(itemCode & vbNullString) = vbNullString Then
        calculateWeight = 0
        Exit Function
    End If

    If Trim(quantityVal & vbNullString) = vbNullString Then
        calculateWeight = 0
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    If quantityVal = 0 Then
        calculateWeight = 0
        Exit Function
    End If

    Dim widthVal As Variant
    Dim lengthVal As Variant
    Dim stdWeight As Double
    
    ' If the itemtype isn't set, search from inventory
    If Trim(itemType & vbNullString) = vbNullString Then
        itemType = "Inventory"
    End If
    
    If itemType = "Inventory" Or itemType = "Remnant" Then
        widthVal = DLookup("Width", itemType, "Code='" & itemCode & "'")
        lengthVal = DLookup("Length", itemType, "Code='" & itemCode & "'")
        stdWeight = DLookup("STD_Weight_Per_Ft", itemType, "Code='" & itemCode & "'")
    Else
        MsgBox ("Error: Invalid item type.")
    End If

    calculateWeight = -Int(-(widthVal * lengthVal * quantityVal) / 144 * stdWeight)

Exit Function

ErrorHandler:

    MsgBox (Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Contact the administrator for more help")

End Function
```

Here is the code for the processing cost calculation:

```vb
Public Function calculateProcessingCost(itemCode As String, weightVal As Long, itemType As String, percentageVal As Double) As Currency

    ' If any of the fields are empty, set cost to 0
    If Trim(itemCode & vbNullString) = vbNullString Or Trim(weightVal & vbNullString) = vbNullString Then
        calculateProcessingCost = 0
        Exit Function
    End If

    If Trim(itemType & vbNullString) = vbNullString Then
        calculateProcessingCost = 0
    End If

    Dim avgCost As Currency
    
    If itemType = "Inventory" Or itemType = "Remnant" Then
        avgCost = DLookup("Average_CWT", itemType, "Code='" & itemCode & "'")
    Else
        MsgBox ("Error: Invalid item type")
        avgCost = 0
    End If
    calculateProcessingCost = Round((weightVal * avgCost / 100) * percentageVal / 100, 2)

End Function
```

Here is the code for generating the remnant code:

```vb
Public Function generateRemnantCode(inventoryCode As String, widthVal As Long, lengthVal As Long) As String

    If Trim(inventoryCode & vbNullString) = vbNullString Then
        generateRemnantCode = ""
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    If Trim(widthVal & vbNullString) = vbNullString Then
        generateRemnantCode = ""
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    If Trim(lengthVal & vbNullString) = vbNullString Then
        generateRemnantCode = ""
        Exit Function
    End If

    ' Get remnant code from product code
    Dim remnantCode As String
    Dim index As Integer
    
    ' Get position of first x. This represents the length.
    index = InStrRev(inventoryCode, "x")
    ' Get position of second x. This represents the width.
    index = InStrRev(inventoryCode, "x", index - 1)
    ' The remnant code will use whatever is to the left of the width
    remnantCode = Left(inventoryCode, index - 1)
    
    'Add the new width and length to the remnant code
    remnantCode = remnantCode & "x" & widthVal & "x" & lengthVal
    
    generateRemnantCode = remnantCode

End Function
```

Comment: Why are you adding this data to a listbox ValueList? Are you saving these inputs to a table? What are formulas for Remnant Code, Weight, and New Cost?

Comment: @June7 I added those details to the question in the EDIT section. Unfortunately, it's working again without me making permanent changes to the code. I added error handlers to all the calculated methods, ran it and it worked fine. Then I removed the error handlers back to the original code and the problem was gone. Very frustrating because this has happened before and there is nothing I can do to accurately reproduce this bug/solve the problem 100% of the time. There has to be something glitchy around adding items to a listbox in access behind the scenes for this to occur.